# Dynamic input and add it into a database

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, database

Hello everybody, likle my title tells I'm making a dynamic input but I have errors and I'm going to cry haha. Seriously I have difficulties to make it. I want to add dynamic input and add value in my database. Here is my code :

```
<?php
// Connect to the DB
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testlp") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

// store in the DB 
if(!empty($_POST['ok'])) {  
    // first delete the records marked for deletion. Why? Because we don't want to process them in the code below
    if( !empty($_POST['delete_ids']) and is_array($_POST['delete_ids'])) {
        // you can optimize below into a single query, but let's keep it simple and clear for now:
        foreach($_POST['delete_ids'] as $id) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM recherche WHERE id=$id";
            $link->query($sql);
        }
    }



    // adding new recherche
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    //  ( $i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES ".$_POST['name'][$i];
            $link->query($sql);
        }
    }   
}

// select existing recherche here
$sql="SELECT * FROM recherche ORDER BY id";
$result = $link->query($sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple example of dynamically adding rows with jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;">
    <h1>Simple example of dynamically adding rows with jQuery</h1>

    <form method="post">
    <div id="itemRows">

     Item name: <input type="text" name="add_name" /> <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add row" /> (This row will not be saved unless you click on "Add row" first)

    <?php
    // let's assume you have the product data from the DB in variable called $recherche
    while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <p id="oldRow<?=$product['id']?>"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name<?=$product['id']?>" value="<?=$product['name']?>" /> <input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[]" value="<?=$product['id']?>"> Mark to delete</p>
    <?php endwhile;?>

    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Save Changes"></p>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I've problem in my loop and I get this error :

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp\www\testing\dynamic-form-fields.html.php on
>   line 51 This is the line 51 in the previous code

```
while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <p id="oldRow<?=$product['id']?>"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name<?=$product['id']?>" value="<?=$product['name']?>" /> <input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[]" value="<?=$product['id']?>"> Mark to delete</p>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

Thanks for support!

**EDIT**

Here the new part of the code you guys helped me with : but nothing happens when I submit to the database. I checked in phpmyadmin of my database.

```
<?php
// Connect to the DB
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testlp") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

// store in the DB 
if(!empty($_POST['ok'])) {  
    // first delete the records marked for deletion. Why? Because we don't want to process them in the code below
    if( !empty($_POST['delete_ids']) and is_array($_POST['delete_ids'])) {

        foreach($_POST['delete_ids'] as $id) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM recherche WHERE id=$id";
            $link->query($sql);
        }
    }

    // adding new recherche
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
    {
        //escape special characters from inputed "name" to prevent SQL injection.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name);
        $link->query($sql);
    }
} 
}

// select existing recherche here
$sql="SELECT * FROM recherche ORDER BY id";
$result = $link->query($sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;">


    <form method="post">
    <div id="itemRows">

     Item name: <input type="text" name="add_name" /> <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add row" /> (This row will not be saved unless you click on "Add row" first)
     <?php
if($result!=false && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <p id="oldRow<?=$product['id']?>"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name<?=$product['id']?>" value="<?=$product['name']?>" /> <input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[]" value="<?=$product['id']?>"> Mark to delete</p>
    <?php endwhile;

}
?>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Save Changes"></p>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here finaly are the result with great guys in this forum !

Feel free to edit or make whatever you want with this code!

```
<?php
// Connect to the DB
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testlp") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

// store in the DB 
if(!empty($_POST['ok'])) {  
    // first delete the records marked for deletion. Why? Because we don't want to process them in the code below
    if( !empty($_POST['delete_ids']) and is_array($_POST['delete_ids'])) {

        foreach($_POST['delete_ids'] as $id) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM recherche WHERE id=$id";
            $link->query($sql);
        }
    }

    // adding new recherche
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
    {
        //escape special characters from inputed "name" to prevent SQL injection.

        $sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)."')";
        $link->query($sql);
    }
} 
}

// select existing recherche here
$sql="SELECT * FROM recherche ORDER BY id";
$result = $link->query($sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;">


    <form method="post">
    <div id="itemRows">

     Item name: <input type="text" name="add_name" /> <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add row" /> (This row will not be saved unless you click on "Add row" first)
     <?php
if($result!=false && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <p id="oldRow<?=$product['id']?>"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name<?=$product['id']?>" value="<?=$product['name']?>" /> <input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[]" value="<?=$product['id']?>"> Mark to delete</p>
    <?php endwhile;

}
?>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Save Changes"></p>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't ever assume** you have data in `$result`.test it before processing it.

```
 <?php
if($result!=false && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <p id="oldRow<?=$product['id']?>"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name<?=$product['id']?>" value="<?=$product['name']?>" /> <input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[]" value="<?=$product['id']?>"> Mark to delete</p>
    <?php endwhile;

}
?>
```

**EDIT**

**FIX THIS PART IN YOUR CODE, to insert multiple rows of form submit**

```
// adding new recherche
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
    {
        //escape special characters from inputed "name" to prevent SQL injection.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)."')";
        $link->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this part it work but last part I really don't know how to do it is adding this code `code  // adding new recherche
 if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
 // ( $i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++)
  {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES ".$_POST['name'][$i];
   $link->query($sql);
  }
 } `

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon, If I'm not wrong then, You want to add multiple rows to database on form submit, right??

Comment: Yep When I submit all the data of the client he enter in the input ( dynamicly) will be add to the database. Exemple If he want to add 5 name in add 5 row and when he finish in the database that save 1- the first name 2- the second  name ...

Comment: I edit my code as you can see think something I forget something stupid from my part.

Comment: Almost! I wondering why nothing happen when i on save my data. Nothing is added in my DB.

Comment: Actually, i forgot to quote string **VALUES('".$name."')**, check query in updated answer.

Comment: like this ? `code  $sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES('".$name."') ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name);` If yes tnothing change if not I'm a real retard haha

Comment: NO, try this `$sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)."')";`

Comment: THAT WORK! I'M GUNNA KICK MY GIRLFRIEND MARRY ME MAN! SRLY YOU SAVE MY LIFE! I'm gonna edit my code for answer if people want to do the samething.